# Why do these global variable vanish between 3 functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three functions, and they are for this example being fired in this order:

```
function editmatch(){
        defaultstyling();
        $('.all_cons').css({display: 'none'});
        $('.confirm_button'+id).css({display: 'inline'});
        storecontents();
        isediting = true;
        $(document).find("td[id^='hero_column"+id+"']").html('<input id="select_hero" type="text" name="select_hero">');
        $(document).find("td[id^='result_column"+id+"']").html("<select name='winloss'><option value='Win'>Win</option><option value='Loss'>Loss</option></select>");
        $(document).find("td[id^='gamemode_column"+id+"']").html('<select name="gamemode"<option value="All Pick">All Pick</option><option value="Captains Mode">Captains Mode</option><option value="Captains Draft">Captains Draft</option></select>');
        $(document).find("td[id^='mmr_column"+id+"']").html('<input id="input_mmr" type="text" name="input_mmr">');
}
```

Summary: function changes the text inside a cell to a 'form' (still not complete). Just before the text inside the cell is changed, the `storecontents()` function is fired. That is here:

```
function storecontents(){   //HOLDS CONTENTS OF ROW
    var herotemp = document.getElementById("hero_column"+id).innerHTML;
    var resulttemp = document.getElementById("result_column"+id).innerHTML;
    var gametemp = document.getElementById("gamemode_column"+id).innerHTML;
    var mmrtemp = document.getElementById("mmr_column"+id).innerHTML;
    alert(herotemp);
}
```

This function stores the text inside the cell before it changes them. Note that these variables are defined globally at the top of my coding page. This alert shows the `herotemp` as its previous html: "Rubick".

Then, a button fires this code (if necessary) to change the content back to the original:

```
function abandonedit(){
       alert(herotemp);
       $(document).find("td[id^='hero_column"+id+"']").html(herotemp);
        $(document).find("td[id^='result_column"+id+"']").html(resulttemp);
        $(document).find("td[id^='gamemode_column"+id+"']").html(gametemp);
        $(document).find("td[id^='mmr_column"+id+"']").html(mmrtemp);
}
```

However the alert in the above function shows that the `herotemp` variable (and all others) are empty. I thought that a globally declared variable was usable in all functions? Have I done something wrong or am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using *var* inside a function, this will declare this variable only **inside** this function. also if you have a variable declared as global with the same name.

to generate a global or to use a global variable just remove the *var*

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the variable usin `var herotemp` you'll have a local (function scope) variable named `herotemp` which prevents you from accessing the global variable `herotemp`.

This should fix your code to the intended behavior.

```
function storecontents(){   //HOLDS CONTENTS OF ROW
    /*var*/ herotemp = document.getElementById("hero_column"+id).innerHTML;
    var resulttemp = document.getElementById("result_column"+id).innerHTML;
    var gametemp = document.getElementById("gamemode_column"+id).innerHTML;
    var mmrtemp = document.getElementById("mmr_column"+id).innerHTML;
    alert(herotemp);
}
```

There are times when you **want** a local (function scope) variable named `x` as well as a global variable named `x`. In order to achieve this you will have to do the following:

```
var x = 3;

function useX() {
    var x = 5;
    alert(x, window['x']);
}
```

Or:

```
var x = 3;

function useX(x) {
    alert(x, window['x']);
}
```

Comment: But it's okay in front of the other 3 variables? :p

Comment: Of course!! I see what you mean. Thank you for your contribution. Such a rookie mistake.

Comment: @Archer, why wouldn't it be OK?

Comment: Okay - sense of humor didn't work there.  You need to remove `var` from the other 3 declarations as well.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know which variables need to be globals and which don't. `herotemp` was the only one mentioned in the text so that's what I fixed.